# Dafny: Library of common operations such as partition?

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I'd like to partition a sequence `s` with a predicate `p`, producing two sequences `is_p` and `not_p`. Post conditions would be that every element in `p` is now in `is_p` or `not_p`, in the appropriate order and nothing else is in them.

These seems like something that others would have already done. Is that likely? Is anyone building a library of useful Dafny code? Is there any way to search for such bits of Dafny code? Do people do GitHub code searches?

Comment: I ended up writing a 'partition' from scratch. It was based on the library's "partition" but customized. For details, see our write up in Part 4 of  https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-to-formally-validate-rust-algorithms-with-dafny-part-1-5cb8c8a0bb9 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is effort to build dafny library, see [library](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries). Particular function you are looking for is [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/blob/master/src/Collections/Sequences/Seq.dfy#L678)

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the library. I did a "git clone" and put it in its own folder. Then, in a Dafny file, I did 
include "../libraries/src/Collections/Sequences/Seq.dfy"
import opened Seq
When I F5 run, I get "(3009,40): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Abs' does not exist in the namespace 'Math' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I am able to use it according to above method. Are you verifying only or trying to build it to run binary

Comment: Thanks for checking. On my machine, it seems to be related to there being two Math.dfy files in the library. I found a work around and reported the problem https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/issues/139